# How to rewrite URL when the file is not found with IIS URL Rewrite Module

Tags: php, iis, url-rewrite-module

I need to run a PHP application on IIS and I am trying to port the htaccess rules that look like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [NE,L]
</IfModule>
```

I have zero experience with htaccess but I am being told that these rules state that if the file is not found the request should be sent to index.php and the query string should be carried over. Note that this is not a redirect of the user's browser but pure server operation that transfers all the post data.

So how do I create these rules with IIS URL Rewrite module? What is the rule I should use to rewrite the URL based on missing file on the original address? I'm trying to do this on IIS7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the IIS URL Rewrite module you should be able to import your .htaccess straight in.

When you're on the site you need this for within IIS, double click URL Rewrite icon, then on the right hand side there is an 'Import Rules...' link. Click this, bosh in your .htaccess, click 'Import' and all should work.

HTH

Comment: This is pretty cool. I got some errors with the flags but for now we can just remove them and it works well enough for testing. Thank you very much I can't believe I did not hit an article that mentions this feature when I was searching around the web.